# Изменение направления текста во вкладках

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте! У меня вопрос. Как можно изменить направления текста во вкладках, в элементе управления TabControl. Вот стандартное расположение, свойство **Alignment = Top**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот здесь **Alignment = Left**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить направление текста, что бы он был нормальным. Если кто-то сталкивался с таким вопросом, подскажите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое решение лежит на MSDN:
[Практическое руководство. Отображение расположенных сбоку вкладок с помощью TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms404305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Отображение вкладок с выравниванием по правому краю

1. Добавьте элемент `TabControl` в форму.
2. Задайте свойству `Alignment` значение `Right`.
3. Присвойте свойству `SizeMode` значение `Fixed` так, чтобы все вкладки имели одинаковую ширину.
4. Для свойства `ItemSize` установите необходимый фиксированный размер вкладок. Имейте в виду, что свойство `ItemSize` ведет себя так,
   как если бы вкладки располагались вверху, несмотря на то что они
   выровнены по правому краю.Таким образом, чтобы увеличить ширину
   вкладок, нужно изменить свойство `Height`, а чтобы сделать их выше,
   изменить свойство `Width`.

   Для получения оптимальных результатов в примере кода ниже свойство `Width` имеет значение `25`, а `Height` — значение `100`.
5. Задайте свойству `DrawMode` значение `OwnerDrawFixed`.
6. Определите обработчик для события `DrawItem` элемента `TabControl`, выводящий текст слева направо.

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       // Remove this call if you do not program using Visual Studio.
       InitializeComponent();

       tabControl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl1_DrawItem);
   }

   private void tabControl1_DrawItem(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
   {
       Graphics g = e.Graphics;
       Brush _textBrush;

       // Get the item from the collection.
       TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

       // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
       Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

       if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
       {

           // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
           _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
           g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
       }
       else
       {
           _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
           e.DrawBackground();
       }

       // Use our own font.
       Font _tabFont = new Font("Arial", (float)10.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

       // Draw string. Center the text.
       StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
       _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
       _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
       g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
   }
   ```

Comment: Уважаемый LamerXaKer! Спасибо Вам!

Comment: Ссылки имеют свойство умирать. Включите в ваш ответ нужную часть кода.

Comment: Благодарю, исправился.